# Magento 1: best approach to change product prices on the fly

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, event-observer, collection

So I have this requirement where I need to round product prices based on several criteria for one specific currency.

So when watching the catalog (category view / product view whatever) the prices need to be updated on the fly.

I managed to get it right by using the following observer:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_get_final_price>
            <observers>
                <update_price_on_the_fly>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Vendor_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>roundPrice</method>
                </update_price_on_the_fly>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_get_final_price>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Then in my observer I did:

```
public function roundPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    // check if are using NZD conversion
    if (!preg_match("/NZD/i", $code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())) {
        return;
    }

    $newPrice = $this->_getPriceLogic($observer->getProduct());
    $observer->getProduct()->setFinalPrice($newPrice);
}
```

That **works fine for the product view page but does not work on the category page**. It seems like `catalog_product_get_final_price` event is not dispatched on the category page.

I tried to observer `catalog_product_collection_load_after` event and use the following code but it does not seem to work entirely.

Instead of displaying my rounded price is displays:

`rounded price as low as original price`

```
public function roundPriceCollection($observer) {

    // check if are using NZD conversion
    if (!preg_match("/NZD/i", $code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())) {
        return;
    }

    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $products = $observer->getCollection();
    foreach( $products as $product ) {
        $product->setFinalPrice($this->_getPriceLogic($product));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Thus I'm wondering what is the best approach to implement such feature.

Comment: I posted the same problem on the old forum a million years ago, but that does not work anymore: https://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=10777. All I remember is that the `catalog_product_get_final_price` method is not dispatched for collections.  The recommendation from the core team was to use `catalog_product_collection_load_after` as you tried and it involved changing the attribute `price` in the base currency so the conversion ends up at a rounded value.

Comment: @Marius see my edit. Basically using `catalog_product_collection_load_after` displays `rounded price as low as original price`

Comment: That's why you need to change `price` and `final_price` and other prices, so it will look like the original price is the rounded value.

Comment: @Marius Imma make some tests ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Marius, @Vinai and @AndreasVonStudnitz here's how I managed to get it right.

So the `catalog_product_get_final_price` is only for display purpose on the product view page and the final price from the category and checkout pages come from the price index database table.

Thus I was right using `catalog_product_collection_load_after`

However, to fix the As Low As display issue I had to add the following code to my observer code:

```
$product->setPrice($this->_getPriceLogic($product));
$product->setMinimalPrice($this->_getPriceLogic($product));
```

Of course, as this was for a simple product not on sale it was an easy case and I'll probably have some adjustements to make in order to get it working for every case but I got the idea now.

Comment: Did you find lot of troubles with this, making that custom price prevail during the whole checkout process? I need to do something like that

Comment: @RaulSanchez not really apart from the issue I faced in my question and solved by my answer I didn't face any issue

Answer (score 2):

A wild idea.
You say that it works for the product details page because the event `catalog_product_get_final_price` is triggered.
How about making it trigger in the list page?
The event is not triggered in the event page because the `getFinalPrice` method looks like this:

```
public function getFinalPrice($qty=null)
{
    $price = $this->_getData('final_price');
    if ($price !== null) {
        return $price;
    }
    return $this->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice($qty, $this);
}
```

The event is dispatched in the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::getFinalPrice`.
You can try to rewrite the method 
it means the `getFinalPrice` from the product model and skip the verification for `$price = $this->_getData('final_price');` when the currency is `NZD`.
Or change it to something like

```
public function getFinalPrice($qty=null)
{
    $price = $this->_getData('my_final_price'); //change the attributehere
    if ($price !== null) {
        return $price;
    }
    return $this->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice($qty, $this);
}
```

then rewrite the `getFinalPrice` method from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price` and make sure it sets the value for `my_custom_price` also.
And in order to make sure you don't get in the list something like `regular price / promo price` apply your price logic to the `price` `minimal_price` and `special_price` and all other prices that might be involved in the `price.phtml` file.
I didn't test this, but it looks like it's worth a try.

Comment: See my answer, still a +1 for the help getting the idea =)

Answer (score 0):

For update pricing or any product attribute like name, description, you can use the event catalog_product_collection_load_after and php observer function would be like below.

`public function priceupdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
                $products = $observer->getCollection();
                foreach( $products as $product )                {
                    $product->setMinimalPrice($priceincfriegt);
                    $product->setPrice($priceincfriegt);
}
return $this;
}`