# Programmatically change price in product and catalog pages

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, price, product-attribute

I need to set the price of a product dynamically (based on the value of a variable that I will populate) when the catalog and the product page are loaded.

Currently I use this code in the Module of a `catalog_controller_product_view` observer:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$product = $event->getProduct();
$product_id = $product->getId();

function setPrice($item, $new_price){
  $product->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
  $product->save();
}
switch($product_id){
  case 22116:
    $new_price = 9999;
    setPrice($item, $new_price);
    break;
  case 22076:
    $new_price = 9999;
    setPrice($item, $new_price);
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

The code cause a 404 error page. Any idea why? Is the `catalog_controller_product_view` event the right one to use?

Comment: Please check system.log and exception.log file. and you want to change price for added to cart only or update price for this product permanently.

Comment: I don't want to modify the price permanently in magento, but just display a modified price and keep the modified price when the product is added to cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, there is no need to save that price using save function at product view page load. just follow step or instruction.

> 1) In catalog/product/view.phtml display price according to your
>   populated dynamic variable.

```
2) Update this price in cart while add to cart event using observer and checkout_cart_product_add_after event(check this in below reference URL answer).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270261/magento-how-to-change-item-price-when-adding-it-into-the-cart
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: just to clarify: does save() function save the price permanently?

Comment: Yes dear in catalog :)

Comment: does it change it only for the active user/session of for everybody/everywhere? I would like to change the price everywhere just for some specific sessions.. I think your suggested approach works but I would like to do it all - if possible - in one observer ...

Comment: Above my solution is update price for particular user/customer only. and your solution will update price for all everywhere and everybody.

Comment: I didn't want to add logic to the templates file so I ended up using two observers: `catalog_product_load_after` and `priceupdate_observer` for editing the price on product pages and on cart..now I miss the third one for the catalog view...

Answer (score 1):

Please use `catalog_product_collection_load_after` instead of `catalog_controller_product_view`. then put your logic.

[Aslo see here it might help you.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117643/magento-1-best-approach-to-change-product-prices-on-the-fly)

Comment: the names of the two events you mentioned looks similar :)